# Template Syntax error: Caught GEOSException while rendering: GeoJSON output only supported on GDAL 1.5+

Tags: django, gdal, geos

I am having a problem rendering a polygon stored in PostGIS into json on a template. I am using `{{ geom.json|safe }}` in the template, and get back the error in the subject line.

When I open up the django shell to step through the process, it works. My gdal version is 1.9, and calling geom.json returns, you know, a geojson representation of the polygon.

I am at my wits end with this problem. It only comes up on pages that are trying to render a polygon, and everything else appears to be in line.

Any ideas are *much* appreciated.

***EDIT***

This may be something having to do with my setup overall. I wrote a view that would spit out the results of gdal.HAS_GDAL, and it returns False. In the shell, again, Gdal is there and >1.5.

Taking {{ hood.geom.json }} out of the template solves the problem, but that sort of defeats the purpose. I want to have the neighborhood on a map.

Thanks for the ideas so far.

Comment: it is cribbing about a syntax error. Are you sure this is where the error is ? Try removing this code and see if the error is indeed here ?

Comment: Mine more minerals.... I mean, adding more code (both template and view) might help us better understand what the error is.

Comment: I don't know what the issue was, exactly, but essentially there was a problem with running an older version of Django with a new version of PostGIS. I upgraded Django and everything worked.